# optimising single threaded application running multiple times

Tags: .net, process

I've got a simple non-blocking, single threaded .net console application copied to X number of folders and I open up multiple console windows and run each application from each folder once. The application is long running and performs a set number of tasks (reads from a database, makes a web-service call)

How does Windows or .NET handle this affinity? will they or could they be made to run on separate processors (I have 8) so they don't block each other in the same processor, or is this something Windows will handle implicitly because I'm not getting an increase in performance that I expected.

Is it perhaps a simple case of using Task Manager and assigning each console window's affinity? if so, do I set cmd.exe or it's associated conhost as every console window I open I get a conhost too.

Thanks.

Comment: By default, no affinities are set and so processes should be free to use any available processors. If you're not getting an expected speedup, look for other issues - e.g. if you're launching more than the number of cores/processors then the system may be spending more time scheduling than running. Or perhaps your application relies on some other resource that is inherently non-sharable. Not easy to tell from what you've posted.

Comment: Easy to see with Task Manager.  If 8 processes can keep the processor busy then CPU utilization will be 100%.  But it won't be, it is not the processor that is the critical resource.  You have only 1 dbase server and only 1 network connection, probably only 1 web server.  So it is I/O bound and it doesn't scale.   You can only get ahead by spending more money.

Comment: Thanks. I have 8 cores and I'm running 6 instances of my program. I have a gigabit LAN and performance counters shows IIS is coping just dandy and creating enough worker threads. I'm also using enterprise SQL Server which has no issues either. btw, I have plenty money (well I can easily have more virtual boxes spun up).